# JPEG2000 change progression order without decoding

Tags: gdal, jpeg-2000

I wonder if there is a way to change the progression order of jpeg2000 image, without the need of decoding it and then encode it again.
For example if I have an image with RPCL progression and I want to convert it to LRCP.
Is there away to only move bits around (change the order of the file) instead the need to transcode the image all over again (which may take long time)?

Comment: It is just transcoding that is fast (at least it is the term that Kakadu is using. I do not know how well GDAL can do that with any of the JP2 drivers that it has, or if it needs to go through decompress-recompress cycle. The Kakadu kdu_transcode demo utility is super fast.

Comment: You've used the GDAL tag, but haven't included that in your question.  Without that, the question looks like an image processing question, not a GIS question, in which case it would not be a suitable question for this site.  Can you edit the question to make it a bit more GIS-centric (eg, include how you want to use GDAL to do this)?

Comment: @ Son of a Beach
Well I guess that if there is a way to do it, it will be some option at gdal using driver such as Kakadu or OpenJpeg. So I am looking for this option, that will enable it.

Comment: @user30184 for my testing the transcoding between the progression types is very slow (at least for very large Images). So I am looking to see if there is another way to do it.

Comment: What software did you use? I tried kdu_transcode for changing 12000 x 12000 sized RGB image from LRCPinto  RPCL and it took 1 second. Kdu_transcode is an application that is written to demonstrate the transcoding capabilities of the Kakadu SDK and it is not useful for real work (for example, it cannot output .jp2 file but only j2k codestream). However, I think that the result proofs that it is possible to re-organize the JPEG2000 image, and that it can be fast. But GDAL drivers lack the transcoding (I mean re-organizing the encoded stream) features.